# How jTable change cell color on a specific row. Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I made a java application to manage tasks.

My application is connected to a MySQL database.

I need the table rows where the priority is equal to 1 change color automatically. I've been searching and found some examples, but I couldn't do to work with my table. 
My table was made using drag and drop, so it is the default type as you can see through the code.

Does anyone could help me try to implement this functionality in my small application please?

I'm really discouraged.

Sorry everyone.

Can anyone help me please?

Code of my jtable

```
DefaultTableModel tmTasks = new DefaultTableModel(null, new String[]{"Status", "Priority", "Task", "Desc", "Date"});
List<Tasks> tasks;
ListSelectionModel lsmTasks;




private void showTasks(List<Tasks> tasks) {
        while (tmTasks.getRowCount() > 0) {
            tmTasks.removeRow(0);
        }
        if (tasks.size() == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO Tasks");
        } else {
            String[] line = new String[]{null, null, null};
            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
                tmTasks.addRow(line);            
                tmTasks.setValueAt(tasks.get(i).getStatus(), i, 0);
                tmTasks.setValueAt(tasks.get(i).getPriority(), i, 2);
                tmTasks.setValueAt(tasks.get(i).getTasks(), i, 1);
                tmTasks.setValueAt(tasks.get(i).getDesc(), i, 3);
                tmTasks.setValueAt(tasks.get(i).getDate(), i, 4);
            }
        }
    }
```

My jtable to tasks!

[image]

Comment: whats problem with question asked yesterday,

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable in local variable, as aside double click is accelerator for TableCellEditor,

Comment: I do not want to always be carrying this with questions and make me boring for not getting help, so try to do things differently not to massacre the people who so kindly try to help me.

Comment: You are talking about double-click ? where's it code ? for you information you can use `e.getClickCount==2`, here `e` is `MouseEvent`.

Comment: Thank you @mKorbel what is SSCCE/MCVE?

Comment: @user3145373ツ the title was wrong. excuse me please.

Comment: @user3686971 : how could you make such mistake ? Though also fine.

Comment: Because my English is not great thing and sometimes I use the translator. And I used the wrong copy past :( @user3145373ツ

Comment: Okay okay fine man.. :)

Comment: @rpirez [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), read [Oracle tutorial How to use Tables - Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) if some of your requirements meets with ...

Comment: @rpirez My table was made using drag and drop, so it is the default type as you can see through the code. - read [Default DnD Support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/defaultsupport.html), for [working code example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/dnd/FillViewportHeightDemoProject/src/dnd/FillViewportHeightDemo.java)

Comment: @rpirez I need the table rows where the priority is equal to 1 change color automatically - don't forget convert index from view to model in the case that [JTables view is Sorted or Filtered](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a cell renderer for your table. Something like this

```
public class PriorityCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (Integer.valueOf(1).equals(table.getValueAt(row, 1))) {
            setForeground(Color.RED);  // or background
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Installing of renderer:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new PriorityCellRenderer());
```

Comment: Integer == Integer, not equals

Comment: @mKorbel why not? table.getValueAt() returns Object, so I either need to cast the value or use equals.

Comment: Thanks for reply @SergiyMedvynskyy. I try the code you gave me. And change color of all rows :S even I changing the values ​​of priority from table to 1 and 2 for testing.

Comment: @rpirez sorry but i cannot understand. is foreground of all rows is red now or only foreground of rows with priority 1?

Comment: I solve my problem edit a litle thing in that code ;)

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy One litle question. When I selected a row that change color. I don't want this. How can I remove that functionality??

Comment: @rpirez It's easy. Change the super call of the renderer to
super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, value, false, hasFocus, row, column);

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Is that possible to change color only for the first column??

Comment: @rpirez of course it's possible. Add an appropriate condition to the "if" statement of renderer.

Comment: Could you show an pratical example please?

Comment: if (Integer.valueOf(1).equals(table.getValueAt(row, 1)) && 0 == column)

Comment: Thank you very, very much, seriously. 
Works great, however is working contrary to what I wanted. Instead of being the first colored column are the others except the first: S 
How can we change this?